# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlLinkButton' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi am using below code to get the value. this was worked fine earlier but now it is generating error.

```
   TextBox message= (TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that some other control is now at index 0.
BTW this is generally a bad solution. Either use a name, or if you add the control dynamically, tag the one and search for it using LINQ like:

```
TextBox message= (TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls.Where(c=>c.Tag.ToString()=="your tag").First();
```

Comment: @mukeshvishwas would you please mark my answer as a solution?